# Why Does This subquery only return one record?

Tags: sql

this is a subquery that I have. I am having a hard time understanding why this keeps popping back to me saying ("at most this subquery can only return one record")

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM SoftwareAssigned
GROUP BY SoftID
```

By my understanding this is saying "get a count of all records where the SoftID (softwareID) is the same"

What is really going on and how do I keep from making this mistake in the future?

The context is within this (attempted query:)

```
SELECT Software.Description, Software.QtyPurchased
, (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM SoftwareAssigned
  GROUP BY SoftID
) AS Assigned
,( Software.QtyPurchased - 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM SoftwareAssigned
    GROUP BY SoftID
  ) 
) AS Remaining
FROM Software
;
```

Comment: You have a query and not a subquery.  This query returns more than one row.  Apparently, it is being used in a context where a scalar subquery is expected, so returning more than one row is a problem.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Post your entire query.

Comment: Just added the full context of my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `Sofware` has a `SoftID` column. It looks like you are hoping SQL will link between the sub query and the main query. It will only do ths if you tell it how:

```
select
    s.Description,
    s.QtyPurchased, (
        select
            count(*)
        from
            SoftwareAssigned a
        where
            -- link to outer query
            a.SoftID = s.SoftID
    ) as Assigned,
    s.QtyPurchased - (
        select
            count(*)
        from
            SoftwareAssigned a
        where
            -- link to outer query.
            a.SoftID = s.SoftID
    ) as Remaining
from
    Software s;
```

As it happens, there is a more compact way of writing this:

```
select
    s.Description,
    s.QtyPurchased,
    count(a.SoftID) as assigned,
    s.QtyPurchased - count(a.SoftID) as Remaining
from
    software s
        left outer join
    SoftwareAssigned a
        on s.SoftID = a.SoftID
group by
    s.SoftID,
    s.Description,
    s.QtyPurchased;
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e7b69/3)

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize I needed to join the inner query to the outer one. Thank you also for the great example. :)

Answer (score 1):

The query will "get a count for each specific SoftID value how many there are that has that id".

The query will return one row for each specific SoftID value that exists in the table.

If you want to count how many different SoftID values there are, you would use:

```
select count(distinct SoftID)
from SoftwareAssigned
```

#### Edit:

To get a count from one table of the records that correspond to a record in another table, you would join the tables together and group on the values from the other table:

```
select
  Software.Description, Software.QtyPurchased,
  count(SoftwareAssigned.SoftID) as Assigned,
  Software.QtyPurchased - count(SoftwareAssigned.SoftID) as Remaining
from
  Software
  left join SoftwareAssigned on SoftwareAssigned.SoftID = Software.SoftID
group by
  Software.SoftID, Software.Description, Software.QtyPurchased
```

Comment: "The query will 'get a count for each specific SoftID value how many there are that has that id'." This is exactly what I am looking to do, but cannot seem to accomplish with the above syntax (I did update the question to include my full code). My intent is to get the number of software licenses purchased, the number assigned to students, and the number left in stock after assignment.

Comment: @JacobDonahoe: If you want a list of how many there are of each id, then you can't return all that as a single value. From your query I understand that you want the count for just one id in each record. See my edit above.